# moving arrowhead across its body

Tags: python, vector, trigonometry, vertices

I have created the following function which gets two line points and outputs three points of an arrowhead triangle. What I need to add is a length according to which the arrowhead will be poisitioned away from the point B across the line AB. To explain it better, I would like it like this: A----->--B where the two dashes are equal to the length

```
def create_arrowhead(A, B):
    """
    Calculate the arrowheads vertex positions according to the edge direction.

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : array
    x,y Starting point of edge
    B : array
    x,y Ending point of edge

    Returns
    -------
    B, v1, v2 : tuple
    The point of head, the v1 xy and v2 xy points of the two base vertices of the arrowhead.
    """
    w = 0.005 # half width of the triangle base
    h = w * 0.8660254037844386467637  # sqrt(3)/2

    mag = math.sqrt((B[0] - A[0])**2.0 + (B[1] - A[1])**2.0)

    u0 = (B[0] - A[0]) / (mag)
    u1 = (B[1] - A[1]) / (mag)
    U = [u0, u1]
    V = [-U[1], U[0]]
    v1 = [B[0] - h * U[0] + w * V[0], B[1] - h * U[1] + w * V[1]]
    v2 = [B[0] - h * U[0] - w * V[0], B[1] - h * U[1] - w * V[1]]

    return (B, v1, v2)
```

Comment: what circle are you talking about, and 'where the two dashes are equal to the radius' which 2 dashes? Is the arrow pointing towards A or towards B?

Comment: Excuse me, not radius, a scalar variable of length. The arrow points always towards B

Comment: and what problem are you facing in your code? Also what 2 dashes, the ones between Point B and the arrowhead, how many dashes are there between A and B what is their length, do they depend on the total length between A and B?

Comment: what are u0 and u1, if that is the mid point of line segment then it should be (B[0] + A[0]) / (2) and (B[1] + A[1]) / (2) respectively, otherwise please explain what they are and the problem you are facing?

Comment: I used dashes in order to be easier to visualize. It is just an example. Imagine them as a line. U is the unit vector from A to B and V is the perpendicular unit vector to AB. These are used to find the triangle's base vertices. I want my code to create the same vertices, positioned not on the edge B but moved by some variable length L between B and A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. By multiplying a variable of distance with the unit vector's components and subtracting this result from B's coordinates. This will create a point on the line AB with distance d from B.

```
def create_arrowhead(A, B, d):
"""
Use trigonometry to calculate the arrowheads vertex positions according to the line direction.

Parameters
----------
A : array
    x,y Starting point of line segment
B : array
    x,y Ending point of line segment

Returns
-------
C, v1, v2 : tuple
    The point of head with distance d from point B, the v1 xy and v2 xy points of the two base vertices of the arrowhead.
"""
w = 0.003 # Half of the triangle base width
h = w / 0.26794919243 # tan(15)

AB = [B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1]]
mag = math.sqrt(AB[0]**2.0 + AB[1]**2.0)

u0 = AB[0] / mag
u1 = AB[1] / mag
U = [u0, u1] # Unit vector of AB

V = [-U[1], U[0]] # Unit vector perpendicular to AB

C = [ B[0] - d * u0, B[1] - d * u1 ]

v1 = [C[0] - h * U[0] + w * V[0], C[1] - h * U[1] + w * V[1]]
v2 = [C[0] - h * U[0] - w * V[0], C[1] - h * U[1] - w * V[1]]

return (C, v1, v2)
```